# Dumps Not Write To JSON file Pretty Print I Already using "indent=4" I added JSON View

Tags: python, json, dump, pretty-print

I'm trying to convert a dict that I can't serialize to string type and write it to a json file. However, when using the dumps method, pretty printing does not occur in the json file.

```py
    data = ''
    for db_name in client.list_database_names():
            db = client[db_name]
            for coll_name in db.list_collection_names():
                data += str("DATABASE NAME: {}, Collection:{}".format(db_name, coll_name))
                data = json.dumps(data, default=str)
                json.loads(data)
     return data
```

Here is the result: [JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IsHn.png)

Comment: The question code has several problems which seem odd and make it less relevant to the stated question: 1) there's no file output. 2) You're wrapping a string with `str()`, making a redundant type conversion. 3) You're passing a string to `json.dumps()`, but that function expects a dict or list structure. 4) The return value of `json.loads()` isn't assigned to a variable.  Please review https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html for sample usage

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the indent argument in `json.dumps()` to create the pretty effect.

```
with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get pretty printing using `json.dumps()` you need to include a parameter like `indent=4`.  See the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Update, after seeing the image:

The problem you have here is that in your JSON, `DbCollectionName` is a string that contains more JSON.  This is "Nested JSON".   You need to call `json.loads()` on each of those strings to convert them to objects.

Comment: I already use this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ÖmerYüce If this doesn't work, please include the code you used in your question, along with a sample JSON structure and how it appears in the file.

Comment: @SarahMesser Can you check, I added screenshot JSON file.

Comment: @ÖmerYüce Please avoid screenshots https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: From your code, you're not passing a dict. You're passing a string. The screenshot is consistent with that.